# How do i shutdown my heroku app?

Tags: heroku, shutdown

I've slowly battled through to the point where I have a working Grails app on Heroku. I'm going to bed now so I want to shut it down so I don't continue to use up my 750 free hours of my Dyno. It is probably obvious but I can't find how to shutdown my Heroku web server and restart it again in the morning.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To shut down your Heroku app scale the web processes to 0:

> heroku ps:scale web=0

See the [Usage & Billing dev centre article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/usage-and-billing): "A web dyno that is idled continues to accrue usage". I believe maintenance mode will continue to accrue time; it [simply serves a static page to visitors](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maintenance-mode) instead of serving your app.

Keep in mind each app receives 750 free billing hours [*per month*](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/usage-and-billing#750-free-dynohours-per-app). Depending on your intended usage, this may mean you don't need to shut down (i.e. if you only plan to run a single dyno for the whole month).

Answer (score 23):

From web:
Personal => Your App Name => Overview => Configure Dynos => Click on edit against web => Flip the switch => Confirm

Comment: Thank you @Sunny, I can't believe they made this so hard to find! It also took more Googling than I care to admit!

Answer (score 13):

To stop a DYNO you can use:

```
heroku ps:stop "appname"
```

To get list of running appnames you can use:

```
heroku apps
```

Comment: Looks like the syntax has changed to `heroku ps:stop --app "myapp"`.  Also my web dynos kept magically restarting themselves for some reason, so I went with culix's answer (scaling web dynos down to 0).

Comment: Will this also stop the charges on my database?

Answer (score 4):

Just read the documentation:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#one-off-dynos

Type

```
heroku ps
```

to see all running app associated to you account, with an id associated, then

```
heroku ps:stop run.1
```

if the app you want to stop has the `1` id.

Note that the maintenance mode will not stop your app. Mine was wrongly configured and continued to crash with the maintenance mode enabled.

Answer (score 4):

There's a Maintenance Mode in Settings now in 2019.

[image]

Comment: Dyno hours get counted even in maintenance mode.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe turn on maintenance mode? `heroku maintenance:on`

Comment: @Benjamin I'm not sure this is correct - according to the DevCenter, turning on maintenance mode does not alter your web dynos, it simply serves a static page. I believe hours will continue to accrue unless the web dynos are scaled to 0. I have submitted an answer with this below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the add-on AutoIdle to automatically shutdown:

https://elements.heroku.com/addons/autoidle